# Pysimplegui newb - two of my buttons' texts are getting erased

Tags: python, excel, datetime, pysimplegui

I'm a complete newb to python and came across an easy gui code by Sven from his "Coding is Fun" YT channel.

I was able to customize it and combine it with Amith Ravindar's "PySimpleGUI - Calendar Input, Dealing with Dates and Times" YT video.

It's working but for two issues:

1. When I hit the submit button, all the fields are cleared, as they should, but it also clears the names on the Calendar (Job Start & Job Stop) buttons.
2. It generates 2 additional columns (Job Start & Job Stop) in the Excel file but enters the data into the correct "Clock In" & "Clock Out" columns.  I'm a complete green-horn so the following question is not surprising - "What am I doing wrong?"

Please see the attached code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time

# Add some color to the window
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')

current_dir = Path(__file__).parent if '__file__' in locals() else Path.cwd()
EXCEL_FILE = current_dir / 'ClockInOut.xlsx'

# Load the data if the file exists, if not, create a new DataFrame
if EXCEL_FILE.exists():
    df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame()

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
    [sg.Text('Work Order No.', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Work Order No.')],
    [sg.Text('Part No.', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Part No.')],
    [sg.Text('Employee No.', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Employee No.')],
    [sg.CalendarButton("Job Start", close_when_date_chosen=True, target="Clock In", location =(20,20), no_titlebar=False),
    sg.Input(key='Clock In', size=(15,1))],
    [sg.CalendarButton("Job Stop", close_when_date_chosen=True, target="Clock Out", location =(20,20),no_titlebar=False),
    sg.Input(key='Clock Out', size=(15,1))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]

]

window = sg.Window('Simple data entry form', layout)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        new_record = pd.DataFrame(values, index=[0])
        df = pd.concat([df, new_record], ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)  # This will create the file if it doesn't exist
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()
window.close()
```

I've tried renaming both CalendarButtons from Jobs Start/Stop to match their corresponding "sg.Input(key=" but that only left the field boxes empty.

I'm still learning...slowly.

Comment: Make sure what keys of elements listed in `values` before you clear the content of all those elements. The same, what `values` converted to Dataframe.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of how I can add an exception as to what should NOT be cleared.  I tried the following:
     not_to_clear = ('Job Start', 'Job Stop')

     def clear_input():
         for key in values:
             window[key]('')
         return None

No errors but same issue persists.

Comment: def clear_input(): for key in values: if key not in not_to_clear: window[key].update("")

Comment: @JasonYang, that was it!  You the man - maraming salamat!!!